# Como clicar em duas '<div>' diferentes ao mesmo tempo em dispositivos mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, aplicação-web, mobile

Estou criando um site para tocar notas musicais e para isso preciso clicar em múltiplos botões(divs) ao mesmo tempo, mas quando faço isso nada acontece, apenas quando clico em um botão apenas.
No computador não consegui testar por causa do clique do mouse, mas quando testo no Smartphone o erro fica mais nítido.
Eu acredito que possa ser por causa do zoom em dispositivos mobile que necessitam os mesmos cliques.
Este problema ocorre apenas com o mouse, no teclado funciona normalmente.
**teclado**: q...t, a...g, z...b

```
    function teclasom(id){

        // audio
        let id_audio = $(id).attr('id')
        document.getElementById(id_audio+'audio').load()
        document.getElementById(id_audio+'audio').play()


        // animação
        if($(id).css('transform') == 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)'){ // transform: rotateY(180deg)
            $(id).css({
                'transition': '0.3s',
                'transform': 'rotateY(180deg)'
            })
        }else if($(id).css('transform') == 'matrix3d(-1, 0, -1.22465e-16, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1.22465e-16, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)'){ // transform: rotateY(0deg)
            $(id).css({
                'transition': '0.3s',
                'transform': 'rotateY(0deg)'
            })
        }
    }

$('.botao').on('click', function(){
   teclasom($(this))
})
```

link do site:
https://skysongs.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. Por favor tire algum tempo para completar o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e ler o tópico de ajuda [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Boas perguntas normalmente têm um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). O StackOverflow também tem uma [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) com muita informação. Grato.

Comment: No seu caso faltou o HTML relevante pra gente ver onde vc está aplicando a classe .botao

Comment: Consegui resolver, precisei trocar o evento 'click' pelo evento 'touchstart', que é próprio pros dispositivos mobile. Link da w3schools com a referência do evento:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_touchstart.asp